# How to refer to the columns in pig output

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have a data file that contains values as:

```
A 1
B 2
C 3
C 3
```

I wrote the following pig script.

```
A = load 'users.txt' as (usr: int, nod: int);
B = GROUP A BY usr;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group,COUNT(A);
```

Now, I want to use the output C and process it further. How can I refer to the values/columns in C? I tried DUMPing the data, but they came out as key-value pairs? Do I need to write this output to a file, load it again and process?

Thanks,
TM

Comment: on side note, based on your current schema you will get NULL values in 'column : usr' as you have defined it as 'int' and you have string values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Name the columns when they are created in the following manner:

```
C = FOREACH B GENERATE group as usr,COUNT(A) as countA;
```

they can then be referred to later by these names, as in the following example:

```
D = FOREACH C GENERATE usr, countA;
```

Comment: ...thank you very much...worked like a breeze....this looks very much like SQL alias names..are they called the same in PIG also?

Comment: @user295338 Ya, they are basically the same thing as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 2):

If it is cumbersome to name your columns, for instance if you have a large number of columns, you can also refer to the columns by zero indexed column number. The code equivalent to what Davis Broda posted would look like this:

```
 C = FOREACH B GENERATE group,COUNT(A);
 D = FOREACH C GENERATE $0, $1;
```

Comment: While this is true, I cannot dis-recommend this practice strongly enough.  It makes for unreadable code that is extremely difficult to maintain.  Always name your fields.  If you have a lot of fields in a data source you use a lot, create a macro to do the naming for you.

Comment: I certainly agree. But this still has worthwile use cases, because sometimes you aren't writing scripts/software to maintain. Sometimes you just want to answer a quick question about a piece of data. 

If you are writing Pig that should be maintainable, I suggest using a serialization framework like Avro in the first place rather than using a Pig-specific naming macro.